# "Blind" is to "sighted" as "Deaf" is to..?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the opposite of the adjective deaf?

e.g.

> The seats close to the interpreter are reserved for the hearing impaired. It is
>   imperative that all [not deaf] people sit in the remaining seats.

Comment: *all not deaf people* => *everyone who can hear*?

Comment: @Matt Yes, that's right.

Comment: Please use "interpreter" instead of "signer". Additionally, you might want to say "are reserved for the hearing impaired." Not all people needing a sign-language interpreter are deaf.

Comment: @zzzzBov: But people who are culturally Deaf usually prefer to identify as Deaf instead of "hearing impaired."  It really depends on the audience, but it can be important to distinguish between people who are *medically* deaf versus those who consider themselves deaf.  Generally, people who identify as "hearing impaired" tend to be more orally-oriented and are less likely to be using sign language in the first place.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned people are taking issue with the political correctness of my example text. It is not a real sign. I was only using it to make my point clear. Nevertheless, I have altered it as suggested.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*[Hearing persons](http://thesaurus.com/browse/deaf)* should cover it.

Comment: +1: "hearing" is the word Deaf people use to refer to people who are not deaf.

Comment: "hearing" ... the "persons" is implied since it is a substantive, adjectival participle

Answer (score 5):

*The seats close to the signer are reserved for deaf people. It is imperative that all [not deaf] people sit in the remaining seats.* **might best be replaced with** *The seats with a clear view [1] of the ASL [2] interpreter are reserved for those who are reading the interpreter's signing [3]. Others are asked to sit elsewhere.* After all, [1] visibility, not proximity, is the essential need; [2] not all deaf or hearing-impaired people know ASL, and not all people who know a sign language know ASL; and [3] some people with no hearing impairment know ASL, and like to read it when they have the chance. No reference to hearing impairment need appear in this notice.

Comment: excellent point.  Unfortunately not really the specific question.  But a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

people possessing *aural capability*
should work fine.

Comment: people would see that and say huh? :)

Comment: People can be very stupid.

Answer (score 1):

How about good old "*not deaf*"?